# console.log without arguments? How does this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Probably a very basic question but I haven't found an answer in the docs or Google...

I was doing [nodeschool's](http://nodeschool.io) "learnyounode" module, and for an intro to http client question found an official answer that used `console.log` without arguments (and indeed as args in another function, but that I understand) :

```
var http = require('http')

http.get(process.argv[2], function (response) {
      response.setEncoding('utf8')
      response.on('data', console.log)
      response.on('error', console.error)
  })
```

**How does this work?** It looks clean and obvious, but I'm not sure I can use this style confidently without better understanding what's going on.

---

Btw for comparison (and to see what I'm not understanding), here's my own very similar, but longer answer:

```
var http = require('http');

http.get(process.argv[2], function callback(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf8');
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    response.on('error', function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: because the `console.log` function puts out the elements to the console, it is saying simply that when there is data, output the data to the console log. Same thing with console.error. also, you should end your lines with semicolons otherwise javascript has to try and figure out where they go.

Comment: FWIW, I would not generally recommend doing this. `.log` and `.error` are methods and aliasing their methods changes their `this` value when called, which makes it dependent on implementation-specific behavior. With Node, that's less of an issue, but some console implementations would not work in this manner. You could do something like `console.log.bind(console)` to alias them though.

Comment: Yes, Chrome and Firefox throw error when `setTimeout(console.log, 0)`. If you want to pass console.log, bind it first for safety `console.log.bind(console)`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - You could pass `console.log.bind(console)` and then it would have a proper `this` pointer.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yep, I added that to my comment.

Comment: @Jhecht I think you must put your comment as answer so that he can mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Nah someone else can do it. I super did not explain that we'll enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple look at your code

```
response.on('error', function(error) { 
    console.error(error); 
});
```

What you did there you wrote a callback that get passed the object from the error Event which you can use as error then.

Now let look at the other code

```
response.on('error', console.error)
```

The same is happening the event passes it's object to the callback function which is `console.error` here which takes one or more objects.

So something like

```
let myLog = function(dataToLog) {
    console.log(dataToLog);
}

response.on('error', myLog);
```

Would also work, hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it's clear that the response objects are being passed to the console methods, but to actually use this style I'd like to know more deeply about any qualifications, gotchas, potential trip-ups, as some of the commenters have been pointing out. Otherwise I'll just default to the more verbose, but potentially safer version... which is fine.